# Function mcrypt_encrypt() Not working in Wamp(PHP Version 5.2.6)

Tags: php

When I try to use this mcrypt_encrypt() function I am getting following error.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_encrypt() in C:\wamp\www\PHP_Kit\FORM_PHP\includes.php on line 307

Help Me.

Comment: By "wamp" do you mean the stack or a specific package like WampServer, http://www.wampserver.com ?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure libmcrypt.dll and mcrypt.dll is in your path.

Also make sure you have the following line in php.ini:

```
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the mcrypt module to your PHP installation. Refer to the PHP mcrypt manual here - https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php